# MySQL Error #1064

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

Running this SWL query keeps returning:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 20`

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    `a` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `b` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT "USER",
    `c` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT "0",
    `d` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `e` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `f` TEXT(30) NOT NULL,
    `g` TEXT(30) NOT NULL,
    `h` TEXT(30),
    `i` enum('i1','i2','i3') NOT NULL,
    `j` TEXT(60),
    `k` DATE NOT NULL,
    `l` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `m` VARCHAR(255),
    `n` VARCHAR(255),
    `o` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `p` BLOB NULL,
    `q` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
);
```

### HELP!

Comment: You didn't try reading the error message and looking at line 20?

Comment: I did except I couldn't find the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should remove comma from the last entry:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    `a` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `b` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT "USER",
    `c` INT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT "0",
    `d` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `e` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `f` TEXT(30) NOT NULL,
    `g` TEXT(30) NOT NULL,
    `h` TEXT(30),
    `i` enum('i1','i2','i3') NOT NULL,
    `j` TEXT(60),
    `k` DATE NOT NULL,
    `l` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `m` VARCHAR(255),
    `n` VARCHAR(255),
    `o` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `p` BLOB NULL,
    `q` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,  <--------------- this one
);
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that removing the comma would help.